# How do I fetch response from rest api

Tags: python, api, get, fetch-api

My request look like this:

```
GET /entity/name.json?entity_id=add7cd797ccb92a7934f3352&entity_type=xxxxx&auth_token=xxxx HTTP/host/v1.1
Host: host_ip:rest_api_port
```

How do I fetch response from this call. I am not able to do it using requests library

Comment: What have you tried till now ? Pls share your code

Comment: any specific error that you are facing with request library??

Answer (score 0):

Assign the response to a variable and get json from it.

```
response = requests.get(http://host_ip:rest_api_port/host/v1.1/entity/name.json?entity_id=add7cd797ccb92a7934f3352&entity_type=xxxxx&auth_token=xxxx)

response_json = response.json()
```